# datetime.datetime.strptime to convert a string to datetime it occurs the mistakes unconverted date remands: 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

The csv file has 18 columns and 6 columns of them are  'year','month','day','hours','minutes','seconds', whose data type are all INT,except the columns 'seconds' is float.

Firstly, I have converted the int and float type to string, and then concated them, then used `the datetime.datetime.strptime` to convert them to datetype. But somehow it does not work.

It returns:

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 335, in _strptime
data_string[found.end():])

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 2
```

The code used is:
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    import datetime

```
df=pd.read_csv('/Users/song/PycharmProjects/AAA/nppanda/LASTROW/LASTROW_GTE Aurich.csv')
df.dropna(how='any')
df.columns=['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17']

df['18']=df['12'].apply(lambda x:str(x))
df['19']=df['13'].apply(lambda x:str(x))
df['20']=df['14'].apply(lambda x:str(x))
df['21']=df['15'].apply(lambda x:str(x))
df['22']=df['16'].apply(lambda x:str(x))
df['23']=df['17'].apply(lambda x:str(x))

df['24']=df['18'].str.cat(df['19'],sep='-')
df['24']=df['24'].str.cat(df['20'],sep='-')
df['24']=df['24'].str.cat(df['21'],sep=' ')
df['24']=df['24'].str.cat(df['22'],sep=':')
df['24']=df['24'].str.cat(df['23'],sep=':')

def has_seconds(a_string):
    if a_string.find('.')!=-1:
        transtime=datetime.datetime.strptime(a_string,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    elif a_string.find('.')==-1:
        transtime=datetime.datetime.strptime(a_string,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return transtime   

df['25']=df['24'].apply(has_seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking this with Pandas. If your columns are appropriately named, you can feed directly to [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). In addition, avoid using Python's `datetime` module with Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2015, 12, 20, 15, 10, 3.1234],
                   [2018, 5, 15, 10, 12, 65.432]],
                  columns=['year','month','day','hours','minutes','seconds'])

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df)

print(df)

   year  month  day  hours  minutes  seconds                   datetime
0  2015     12   20     15       10   3.1234 2015-12-20 15:10:03.123400
1  2018      5   15     10       12  65.4320 2018-05-15 10:13:05.432000
```

Note `datetime` values are stored internally as **integers**. It makes sense to avoid this roundtrip which you are currently attempting:

1. `str`, csv input file
2. `int` via `pd.read_csv`
3. `str` via `pd.Series.apply`
4. `int` via `datetime.strptime`.

All very expensive and unnecessary.